# What could be considered an anti-pattern in JMS architectures?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jms, anti-patterns

Is there something we could consider anti-patterns when using JMS/Asynchronous Messaging architectures ?
Sometimes, designs may lead us to prove side effects instead of achieving that performance we are looking for.
What are common cases in which we should take another solution, such as batch processing for example, in place of choosing asynchronous messaging?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherent in the JMS architecture which states you should use batch over asynchronous messaging.

Note: some JMS solutions support batch processing and other messaging solutions often have asynchronous messaging.

What you should consider is; are the features and the performance of the JMS solution suitable for my requirements.  If not, consider something else.  You should design your application so that you can easily change your transport later if it turns out it is unsuitable.